# Basic Javascript doesn't display well (stack Mean)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

It will be a very basic question about a problem I encountered. Nothing is specially hard in the work I intend to do, but I really don't see why it isn't working, as my code is almost the same as some examples in AngularJS documentation.

So here it is : 
I'm trying to create a basic website to entertain myself on developping with Mean Stack). 
I made a mere index.html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>

<html class="ng-scope" ng-app="">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>PreBoot</title>


<!-- Bootstrap import -->
<link href="./bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- just a little CSS -->
<style>
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
    /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}
</style>
</head>    
    <body ng-app="preBoot">
<div id='main'> 
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-    toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PreBoot</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1> PreBoot </h1>
            <p class="lead">zqesiediuhzsbadehzdebshobsezd</p>
            <form ng-submit="post()" ng-controller="mainController">
                <input required type="text" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by"/>
                <textarea required maxLength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Preboot that!"/>
            </form>
            <div id="post-stream">



   <!--  INTERESTING PART  !!!!!!!! --> 



                <h4> PreBoot Feed</h4>

                    <div class='post' ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                        <p> {{post.text}} </p>
                    </div> 
            </div>

      <!-- END OF IT !!!!! -->


          <!-- <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>Bootstrap v3.3.6</li>
                <li>jQuery v1.11.1</li>
            </ul> -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
</div>


        <!-- JScript imports --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./preBoot.js"></script> 

<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And that's for the HTML page, the interesting part is notified. I use a serveur.js file which is following :

```
var app = angular.module('preBoot', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
$scope.posts = []; 
$scope.newPost={created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

$scope.post= function(){
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
    $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
};


});
```

Finally, I run everything using the serveur.js file I run with the node.js invite command.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile('./index.html');
});

// Allow the error 404 selection

/* app.use(function(req, res, next){
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.send(404, 'Page introuvable !');
}); */

app.listen(8081);
```

For simplicity purposes, I temporarly put every single file in the same folder, so everything (every ccs and js file is in the same folder of my html). 
What I get when I run the program is :

[My screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cw80.png)

Which is pretty much what I want except when I type something, the text doesn't appear, which does not make any sense to me.

I correctly installed the npm express before in a node_module folder put in the same place than my index.html file.

Sorry to bother with that uninteresting problem, I spend hours trying to fix that problem and one more searching for any solution in the questions already asked, but everything I found didn't fix the issue.

NB : I work on Windows.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? - press F12 to view the console on Chrome, Ctrl-Shift-K on Firefox (Cmd-Shift-K on OSX).

Comment: Yes I get an error but it seems linked to the angular.js file from google, and I don't really see what to do with that.

The error I get is : 

angular.js:13642Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)

When I click the link, it is explained in the documentation that mainController is called as a function ;
Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: define the ng-app to fixed the error.. Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2927/

Comment: Ensure that you are including your source file from your html page:

`<script src="app.js"></script>` Note: change app.js to the name of your source file.

Comment: You have a typo in the doctype: "hmtl"

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you have defined

```
ng-app=""
```

and you have defined the `controller` on `preBoot` app

```
var app = angular.module('preBoot', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
```

Either define the controller like this

```
function mainController($scope){
```

OR `define the ng-app="preBoot"`

Others mistakes are

Your controller is bound to form only

```
<form ng-submit="post()" ng-controller="mainController">
                <input required type="text" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by"/>
                <textarea required maxLength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Preboot that!"/>
            </form>
```

This code is out of controller scope

```
<div class='post' ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                        <p> {{post.text}} </p>
                    </div>
```

I did short your code and have made a jsfiddle. Working fine.
check it
https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2926/

In jsfiddle code update `ng-app="preBoot"` to `ng-app=""` you will get the error `Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me to understand how it works !